# R: breaks lines wrong

Tags: r, annotations, export

It's my first post here. I'm a beginner in R maybe my problem is not very complicated. 
I used `mygene` package from R to create an annotation for our RNAseq results. It looks nice and it generated a `res` list wit 3 sublists as follows (summary):

```
           Length Class      Mode     
response      8   DataFrame  S4       
duplicates  255   data.frame list     
missing    3584   -none-     character
```

I was interested in the first list `response`
When I'm calling it in R looks ok:

[image: output in R]

but after exporting that as a txt file with that code:

```
write.table(res$response, "res.response_test.txt",quote=F,col.names = T,sep = "\t")
```

In the txt files some lines looks like creaked in wrong places:

[image: output as txt file]

I would be grateful for your help with exporting that result.

Comment: Is it possible for you to attach the output text file since the image is unclear?

Comment: I think what you are seeing is the result of their being more than one element one of the go columns. From your head(res$response) you see that the three go columns are actually lists. ENSG0000000419 probably multiple elements in one or more of those lists.

Comment: Furthermore a DataFrame object is not the same as an R data.frame. You are not telling us enough to help you. Edit your question body to include the code that created this object. (I think it's going to end of being _very_ complicated.)

Comment: improved spelling and formatting